# Seems to obviously be a scam.. need advice on possible outcome

Tags: united-kingdom, scams

I applied for a job entitled 'Freelance Market Research', within 2 hours I recieved an e-mail informing me that I had the job. Already set alarm bells ringing so I said I would be delighted to possibly join the team but could I have more information.

I was then informed that my first task would be receiving a cheque in the post and I was to deduct £640 as my 'wages' and the rest was to be used at a MoneyGram outlet.. to 'review' their service.

Now I know this is shady as hell and I replied saying I was no longer interested, but I feel a little anxious that this company now has my address and phone number.. if this cheque was to still be mailed to me could I just ignore it and destroy it and nothing more could come of it?

I'm guessing that as long as I dont go through with the task or attempting to cash the cheque I'm not doing anything that could get me into bother with the Law right?

Thanks in advance for any advice and sorry it's so long. <3

Comment: Good on you for identifying a scam by acknowledging the warning signs of something being 'too good to be true'. Having your address and phone number is unfortunate, as these may be compromised by future scammers who will again attempt to scam you. As long as you remain on the lookout as you were here, a name, address, and phone number is not sufficient information to steal your identity or otherwise defraud you. Note that in the duplicate question I am suggesting, the scammers also had the person's bank account number - you are in a much better position for not having given that out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I researched the company a little further and there's so many unusual things in their information. Reported them to the job site I used, hopefully no-one else went any further with them.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm guessing that as long as I dont go through with the task or attempting to cash the cheque I'm not doing anything that could get me into bother with the Law right?

Your instincts are on point!

These scams usually revolve around sending the victim a fraudulent check. They ask the victim to cash the check, then forward some money onwards for whatever clever reason they give. You cash the fraudulent check and make a legitimate transfer to the scammer. They scammer gets a legitimate transaction and is gone by the time the bank catches your fraudulent check and it bounces.

In order to avoid the scam *don't send them any money*! Just to err on the safe side, I would highly recommend throwing out the old check too.

> if this cheque was to still be mailed to me could I just ignore it and destroy it and nothing more could come of it?

The scammer way try to prod you into proceeding with the transaction. They may even threaten you legally, but if you ignore them they will most likely give up and move on. If they threaten you physically then you should report them to the police (there's no harm in doing this anyways).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and for calming my nerves :) I researched the company a little further and there's so many unusual things in their information. Reported them to the job site I used, hopefully no-one else went any further with them.